# Webservice sending its WSDL definition as its response

Tags: soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I am sending a SOAP request to a webservice but it is sending its WSDL definition back as its response.

What would lead to this?

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://www.sample.com/test_request" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://www.sample.com/test_request" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema e
```

Code:

```
import javax.xml.soap.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class Test {

    /**
     * Starting point for the SAAJ - SOAP Client Testing
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            // Create SOAP Connection
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

            // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
            String url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxxx.do?WSDL&xxxxxxxxx=qualified";
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

            // Process the SOAP Response
            printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);

            soapConnection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        String serverURI = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxx";

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("a", "http://www.xxxxxxw.com/xxxxxxxx");

        // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("test", "a");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("testid", "a");
        soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("xxxxxxxxx");

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.xxxxxx-xxxxx.com/xxxxxxx/xxxx");


        String username = "123";
        String password = "123";
        String authorization = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode((username + ":" + password).getBytes());
        System.out.println(authorization);
        headers.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authorization);

        headers.addHeader("Proxy-Connection","Keep-Alive");


        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        /* Print the request message */
        System.out.println("Request: ");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();

        return soapMessage;
    }

    /**
     * Method used to print the SOAP Response
     */
    private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
         System.out.print("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
    }

}
```

What have caused this issue?
I am getting proper response from SOAP UI

Comment: Most likely your SOAP request and/or endpoint configuration. The incomplete response is not really helpful to answer your problem. Please show the code for your request.

Comment: @Filburt added update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified in the URL to get the WSDL (Parameter ?WSDL). You need to specify the proper URL for the service operation you want to call.

Comment: where can I get that?

Comment: You have to ask the provider of the service

Comment: You can try upto .com leaving things after that.